# Не могу удалить объект из кластера yandex map api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Делаю карту с кластерами, через **Яндекс АПИ для JS (версия: 2.78)**

Создаю кластеры через `classter = new ymaps.Clusterer({...})`
Кластеры создаются и **появляются на карте**.

По нажатию на кнопку вне области карты, я пытаюсь удалить все кластеры с карты.
`classter.removeAll()`.

Тут же вывожу состояние переменной `clastter` в консоль и вижу что **кластеров в переменной действительно нет**.

Однако **все кластеры остаются на карте**

Я пробовал удалить их через `myMap.geoObjects.remove() || myMap.geoObjects.removeAll()`, но

1 Не могу найти объекты кластеров в `myMap.geoObjects`.

2 Метод `myMap.geoObjects.removeAll()` удаляет с карты все (включая кластеры), а мне это не подходит

Я могу получить список гео-объектов в кластере через конструкцию

```
clusterer.getGeoObjects().forEach(elem => {
 console.log(elem) 
 // Один гео-объект 
}
```

Я не понимаю как это всё связать и **либо удалить гео-объект из кластера и из карты**. Либо **обновить вид карты с новыми кластерами**

*Буду благодарен за любой дельный совет*

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно заставить кластерер перерисоваться. Попробуйте дёрнуть туда-сюда его опции.
Я, правда, работаю не напрямую с кластерерами, а через ObjectManager. Мне в подобных случаях помогли следующие трюки:

```
myObjectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(cluster.id, {preset: 'islands#redClusterIcons', });
myObjectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(cluster.id, {preset: '', });
```

и

```
myObjectManager._hideObjects();
myObjectManager._showObjects();
```

Comment: Виктор, спасибо. Хорошая идея. Попробую положить кластеры в менеджера объектов